# importing files from a folder within local directory React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filesystems

I have a react project. I am trying to grab all of the files from a help folder and store them in an array or object to be iterated throught within a react component. I am not sure how to do this. i tried  a few differnt things....

Here is the directory:
[image]

i tried:

```
import * as files from '../../../public/help/';
```

and

```
var req = require.context('../../../public/images/help', false);
    console.log(typeof req)
    console.log(req)
    req.keys().forEach(function(key){
        console.log(req(key));
    });
```

Comment: take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir this will generate a object with filename as key

Comment: Is there a way to do it using javascript. it is not working properly. @Harish

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of public folder using `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`

in your case the path you want will be `process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/help"`

and this might also work,

`window.location.origin + "/help"`

Comment: where would i put that... out of curiousity.... would it be its own line.

Comment: As a example if you want to access the geocent-offer.pdf inside your help folder, you can access it using process.env.PUBLIC_URL + /help/geocent-offer.pdf in the comonent you want to access

Comment: where would that line of code above go.... would i just put it as its own line in the file in the react object. i am also using typescript soo...

Comment: yes you can access it from anywhere in your code, if you store images inside help folder you can use it like this.<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/help/yourimage.jpg'} />

Comment: if you want to iterate files inside the folder, try list-react-files. https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-react-files

Comment: i am using typescript so it is giving me type issues.do you know how to get around that...